# Linux Firewall ala Outpost

Tags: firewall

Does linux (Ubuntu) have GUI firewall like Outpost. I need it to look out what apps are generate in/oun bound traffic.

Comment: I have GUFW but it not shows the currently apps which are generate traffic. GUFW can just allows/block some IPs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gufw`, which is an gui frontend for `ufw`.

To install it, run

```
sudo apt-get install gufw
```

Comment: I have GUFW but it not shows the currently apps which are generate traffic. GUFW can just allows/block some IPs.

Comment: @Argentina888 Then you need a network sniffing tool like wireshark. A firewall will probably not help. Wireshrak may be too much detailed for you. There must some simpler alternatives, although I know of none.